# How to upgrade nodejs version on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, serverless-framework

Currently I have Azure function and Node.js version `6.5.0` defined by default there. The goal is to upgrade it. I've checked the list of available Node.js versions on Azure, and the latest one is `8.9.4`. I've read some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nodejs-specify-node-version-azure-apps) about it, where 2 ways to do it are mentioned.

**1) package.json**

Put the following configuration to `package.json` file

```
"engines": {
    "node": "8.9.4"
}
```

So I did it, but no success.

**2) Application Settings**

Go to Application Settings, and update the value for `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to `8.9.4`

Here I have 3 issues with this method:

- logging `process.version` in function shows me `6.11.0`. I have no clue why...
- In fact it's Node.js `8.9.4` there, but some ES6 features like `async arrow functions` throws an error
- each time I run `serverless deploy` command it recreates service and resets `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` value to default one, i.e. to `6.5.0`

---

One more issue with Azure Functions: When I deploy a function with changes, Azure Portal web UI still shows me not updated function (old one), while new version of that function is running there. Weird...

Please let me know if any of you faced these issues, and maybe someone knows the reason or even solution. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm. So, are you deploying Azure Functions as part of an App Service plan, or on-demand? I suspect the solutions you tried only work with the former (I haven't deployed on-demand functions, so I'm not really sure).

Comment: It's part of App Service plan, also not aware of on-demand functions. Anyway I need to get current thing working :)

Comment: [This doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#node-version-and-package-management) points out that Azure Functions runtime v1.x is locked at node v6.11, and that you'd need to use Azure Functions runtime v2.x for later versions. Do you know which version of the Functions runtime you're using? Perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: Oh, I was looking to this documentation but missed it somehow.

Comment: No worries - hopefully it helped. I formalized my comment in an answer, just for completeness (with a bit more detail).

Comment: Yes, thank you for your time, it's useful information. I would really like to accept your answer, but @Jerry Liu gave more detailed explanation with testing, so... Anyway thank you for help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> logging process.version in function shows me 6.11.0.

As @David has said, Azure Functions runtime v1(`~1`) locks your node version at `v6.11`.

When changing `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to `8.9.4`, you also need to change runtime version `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` to `beta` in your application settings.

(Note that runtime switch may cause breaking changes, you can create a new function app instead if error occurs.)

And the first method using `package.json` doesn't work in my test.

> some ES6 features like async arrow functions throws an error

After successful update of node version, `async arrow functions` also works fine in my test.

> each time I run serverless deploy command it recreates service and resets WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION value to default one

`serverless deploy` is a command to deploy the whole service. So it's normal to see the recreating(back to default v6.5) happen as there's no parameter for node version in your yml file.

To avoid this, use `serverless deploy -f <functionname>` to deploy specific function instead of the whole app.

> When I deploy a function with changes, Azure Portal web ui still shows me not updated function (old one), while new version of that function is running there

Same thing happened on my side. I found script can be shown correctly in App Service Editor. But in portal and kudu, update fail to display. I also checked log files in kudu, it says `Script for function 'functionname' changed. Reloading.`.

Have opened an [issue](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-azure-functions/issues/116) on github about the last issue we met.

Comment: Thank you for your testing and detailed answer. Clear and helpful :)

Comment: Glad the solution works. And also thanks to @David, his advice is very valuable and saves us hours.

Answer (score 3):

Just to formalize, from my comment: Functions runtime v1 is locked down to a specific Node.js version (6.11.2 currently), per [this reference document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#node-version-and-package-management).

To use a configurable Node.js runtime, you'll, need to upgrade your Functions runtime to v2.x:

[image: Function overview page]

[image: Function app settings, to change runtime]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the **WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION** By checking the nodejs version from 
***D://program files(x86)/nodejs.***
It will list up with all available versions. Choose one and update **WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION**

This worked for me.
I have changed 8.11 to 8.11.1

Answer (score -2):

Go to your App directory you will see iisnode.yml. Make sure that node.js version correctly specified there also. 
There should be something like this:

`nodeProcessCommandLine: some_dir\nodejs\8.9.4\node.exe`

[image]

Comment: Nope, that doesn't affect Azure *Functions*, only Web Apps.  David Makogon's comment has the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your effort @Shamkhal, but it's not what I need.